# Limit and Offset for for storage entries and keys

Tags: polkadot-js, storage, substrate-node

Following the docs for [polkadot js storage](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other/) we are getting entries and keys from the chain. Is there a way to use limit and offset to implement paging. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`getKeysPaged`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs/blob/b1ec075f7d781ac9c5619e9c5ca7b4b4c845b3f8/docs/substrate/rpc.md?plain=1#L643) to get keys with pagination support