# How to query the number of EVM contracts in a chain

Tags: evm, frontier, ethereum

Is there an easy way to query how many EVM smart contracts has been deployed in a Substrate chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by querying chain state for all entries of `EVM::AccountCodes` or `EVM::AccountCodesMetadata` storages and counting them. For each deployed contract, its code is [stored](https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/blob/master/frame/evm/src/lib.rs#L838) in `AccountCodes`.

Keep in mind that depending on the chain this storage might be big and could be really slow to query all entries. If this is the case, use `paged` storage [query](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/10568/2005).

P.S This doesn't take into account precompiles (but they can be manually injected with a dummy code).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!